# Filter property based searches in Artifactory

Tags: artifactory

I'm looking to use the Artifactory property search

https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Artifactory+REST+API#ArtifactoryRESTAPI-ArtifactSearch%28QuickSearch%29

Currently this will pull json listing any artifact that matches my properties.

```
"results" : [
{
    "uri": "http://localhost:8080/artifactory/api/storage/libs-release-local/org/acme/lib/ver/lib-ver.pom"
},{
    "uri": "http://localhost:8080/artifactory/api/storage/libs-release-local/org/acme/lib/ver2/lib-ver2.pom"
}
]
```

I need to be able to filter the artifacts I get back as i'm only interested in a certain classifier. The GAVC Search has this with &c=classifier

I can do it in code if this isn't possible via the interface

Any help appreciated

Answer (score 2):

**Since the release of AQL in Artifactory 3.5, it's now the official and the preferred way to find artifacts.**

Here's an example similar to your needs:

```
items.find
(
    {
            "$and":[
                            {"@license":{"$eq":"GPL"}},
                            {"@version":{"$match":"1.1.*"}},
                            {"name":{"$match":"*.jar"}}
                   ]
    }
)
```

To run the query in Artifactory, copy the query to a file and name it aql.query

Run the following command from the directory that contains the aql.query file

curl -X POST -uUSER:PASSWORD 'http://HOST:PORT/artifactory/api/search/aql' -Taql.query

Don't forget to replace the templates (USER, PASSWORD,HOST and PORT) to real values.

In the example
   The first two criteria are used to filter items by properties.
   The third criteria filters items by the artifact name (in our case the artifact name should end with .jar)

For more details on how to write AQL query are in AQL

---

**Old answer**

Currently you can't combine the property search with GAVC search. 
So you have two options:

- Executing one of them (whichever gives you more precise results) and then filter the JSON list on the client by a script
- Writing an [`execution` user plugin](http://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/User+Plugins#UserPlugins-Executions) that will execute the search by using [the `Searches` service](http://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/User+Plugins#UserPlugins-GloballyBoundVariables) and then filter the results on the server side.

Of course, the later is preferable.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I'll have a play around.

Comment: If you end up with a user plugin, you're welcome to contribute it to https://github.com/JFrogDev/artifactory-user-plugins :)

Comment: User plugins do indeed look interesting. Unsure for this task but will look to see if it's applicable elsewhere and yes if it looks like it could be useful I'll share. Thanks